# Prevent an HTTP client from hitting a server with cache (iphone)

Tags: iphone, ruby, http, browser, caching

Ok, I'm confused. I'm trying to send back the magic headers from my server that will prevent a client from hitting the server again until a resource is stale.

I understand how ETag or Last-Modified works (Validation) - the client will ALWAYS still hit the server, and the server needs to validate the date or etag against the current value to know whether to bother serving up a new one.

Cache-Control and Expires, however, I don't think I understand. I've set the following:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, must-revalidate
```

No matter what I do, my client (my browser, curl, NSURLConnection) always hits the server again on the second request. Is this a client thing? What headers should I send back to get the client to use it's private cache for a certain length of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nathan hints at in his answer, clients can issue a subsequent request with an `If-Modified-Since` header to determine whether or not their cache is stale. If the client receives a `304 Not Modified` response, it will serve the content out of the local cache.

According to [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4) (the HTTP 1.1 specification), the presence of `must-revalidate` within the `Cache-control` header forces clients to re-check their cache's status with the originating server prior to serving out of the cache.

Comment: 1st paragraph - If the client receives 304 Not Modified, will it avoid hitting the server for a while? 

2nd - that doesn't really match what I've read. `must-revalidate` means that the client must follow "your rules" whatever that means.

Comment: oh yeah, that's right-- `must-revalidate` is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference - Mark Nottingham has written a great guide to HTTP caching:

http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL

Answer (score 1):

The server needs to check the `If-Modified-Since` header and return a `304 not modified` header if it wants the browser to keep caching.

Comment: I understand how ETags work. I want to get the client to avoid checking the server at all. Obviously, validation doesn't help me do that. Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding the other kind though?

Comment: Hmm.  I got this working about a year ago, let me look up the details.

Comment: The relevant line in my PHP code for telling the browser not to come back for 24 hours is:
    `$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=".(60*60*24), true);`

Comment: Any good way to test it? Even if I do exactly that with Cache-Control, a refresh in the browser still hits my server.

Comment: I remember `lwp-request` (a perl utility) being indispensible.  And I wrote lots of debugging headers so I could see what was happening.

Comment: I also found [this report of a bug in the way Safari handles the must-revalidate directive](http://mrclay.org/index.php/2009/02/24/safari-4-beta-cache-controlmust-revalidate-bug/) -- that might be a complicating factor in iPhoneland.